# What are the best uses of document stores?

Tags: sql, nosql, couchdb, cassandra, document-based

I have been hearing a lot about document oriented data stores like CouchDB. I understand the uses of BigTable like stores such as Cassandra. After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104624/what-is-the-difference-between-cassandra-and-couchdb), I was wondering what the conditions would be to merit using a document store?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Column-family stores such as Bigtable and Cassandra have very limited querying capabilities. The application is responsible for maintaining indexes in order to query a more complex data model.

Document databases allow you to query the content, not just the key. It will also manage the indexes for you, reducing the complexity of your application.

[Domain-driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) evangelizes the use of aggregates and value objects. [As Ayende points out](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/04/19/that-no-sql-thing-document-databases-ndash-usages.aspx), (complex) aggregates are very natural candidates to be stored as a single document, instead of normalizing them over multiple tables or column families. This will reduce the complexity of your persistence layer. There's also less chance that related data is scattered across multiple nodes, as all the data is contained in a single document.

If your application needs to store polymorphic objects, document databases are also a good candidate. Of course, this could also be stored in Cassandra, but you won't have as much querying capabilities. At least not out of the box.

Think of a document database as a luxurious sports car. It doesn't need a professional driver (read: complex application) to get you from A to B, it has features such as air conditioning and comfortable seats and it will lap the high-scalability track in an acceptable time. However, if you want to set a lap record on the high-scalability track, you *will* need a professional driver and a highly optimized car (e.g. Cassandra), which lacks features such as air conditioning.

Comment: Hey, what a nice description! The only thing I would add is that CouchDB aims to be the Honda Accord of databases, not the Ferrari. However I think they are different metaphors, only related coincidentally.

Answer (score 9):

Another feature of CouchDB is that you can create those aggregations, not as documents stored manually, but as views (which are derived from the stored data, and updated automatically.)

This is like power windows, heated seats, or the kicking stereo.