# How to choose which type of NoSQL to use

Tags: architecture, nosql

There is a great list of various NoSQL database platforms at http://nosql-database.org.  It categorizes each as a "wide column store", "document store", "key-value store", or "graph store".  What I'm not finding is guidance on how to choose which of those 3 categories is most appropriate for a given problem.

What are the pros/cons or strengths/weaknesses of each type?
Which classes of problems is each type best suited for?

To be clear, I'm asking about distinctions between these 3 types of NoSQL systems and *not* specific implementations of them.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is a good [article](http://www.thoughtworks.com/articles/nosql-comparison) (though it doesn't go in depth) on this exact issue on the thoughtworks site.

And [this visual guide](http://blog.nahurst.com/visual-guide-to-nosql-systems) is excellent as well

Comment: the thoughtworks article is just what i was looking for

Answer (score 13):

After searching around a bunch more, I found that the documentation for RavenDB (a document DB) has a very detailed (and seemingly unbiased) comparison of each of these options, how they work, and where they are most appropriate.  For anyone else interested, read Chapter 1 of this document: https://s3.amazonaws.com/daily-builds/RavenDBMythology-11.pdf

Comment: Thanks Rob, even as an ongoing user of many NoSQL solutions I found the opening chapter of this document very insightful in selecting the *type* (not vendor) of NoSQL solution.

Comment: That is a great resource, thanks

Comment: Actually it's quite biased.

Answer (score 5):

I've asked similar questions (but no real duplicates):

- [When to replace RDBMS/ORM with NoSQL/DocumentStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522799/when-to-replace-rdbms-orm-with-nosql-documentstore)
- [When to replace RDBMS/ORM with NoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522069/when-to-replace-rdbms-orm-with-nosql)

Comment: I really like this blurb from that first link:  "Column-family stores such as Bigtable and Cassandra have very limited querying capabilities. The application is responsible for maintaining indexes in order to query a more complex data model.  Document databases allow you to query the content, not just the key. It will also manage the indexes for you, reducing the complexity of your application."